# How to get value to array in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
$array = array("1" => "box of chocolates", "2" => "mylar balloons", "3" => "stuffed animals");
    <?php 
                $productWithItem = $array;
                foreach ($productWithItem as $pwi) {
                ?>
                    <a href="#" id="product_name"><?php echo $pwi->name ?></div></a>
                <?php    
                }
                ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        var value_array = ?;
    });
    </script>
```

I Want get array value from id="product_name", but I don't know get value from on this javascript, you can help me, thank you

Comment: When did PHP get this `' '.join(['array', 'definition', 'syntax'])`?

Comment: This question is poorly worded.  The way the foreach loop is worded, there would be many anchors with the same "product_name" ID.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: @NullUserException 2 mins ago. But valid point. Hai: What he means, is that you are mixing two programming languages.. and the problem is, that they don't mix :/

Comment: @jimbojw: I want get all value product name from code php from id of it, then javascript get this array value

Comment: @Hai Are you running this through Google Translate? I'm sorry, but your English is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are intending to keep your `<script>` in your html code, build your array in php and use `echo`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    var value_array = <?php echo $yourarray ?>;
});
</script>
```

That's not an elegant solution, though.

Answer (score 3):

Make product_name as id into class . now $('.product_name') this will be automatically array of objects

example markup

```
<a href="#" class="product_name">aaa</div></a>
<a href="#" class="product_name">bb</div></a>
<a href="#" class="product_name">cc</div></a>
```

using each you can extract array

```
$('.product_name').each(function(){

  alert($(this).text());

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your array string in the `name` attribute of the `<a>`.
Then you can use jQuery to get it back:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var ele= [YOUR ELEMENT]
    var value_array = $.parseJSON($(ele).attr("name"));
});
```